# String does not exist in current context - C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

For some reason my string: "firstline" is not being picked up in another method. What is the reasoning behind this?

```
public static void test1()
{
..
            string[] linesw = obj1.ReadToEnd().Split(new char[] { '\n' });
            string firstline = linesw[1]; 
..
}

public static void test2()
{
..
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(firstline);
..
}
```

Comment: It's a legal question. Why -1 without explaining?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`firstline` is a local variable and goes out of scope when used in a different method. Promote it as a class variable or as a parameter instead.

As class variable:

```
private static string firstline = String.Empty; // class variable

public static void test1()
{
..
    string[] linesw = obj1.ReadToEnd().Split(new char[] { '\n' });
    firstline = linesw[1]; 
..
}

public static void test2()
{
..
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(firstline);
..
}
```

Or, as parameter when calling `test2()` **from** `test1()`:

```
public static void test1()
{
..
    string[] linesw = obj1.ReadToEnd().Split(new char[] { '\n' });
    string firstline = linesw[1]; 
    test2(firstline);
..
}

public static void test2(string firstline)...
```

Answer (score 1):

You're creating local variable, instead just assign the global variable you already have:

```
string[] linesw = obj1.ReadToEnd().Split(new char[] { '\n' });
firstline = linesw[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

In c#, When you define a variable in a method you can access it only in the defining method. In other words the scope of a variable is the defining block for example:

```
    private void test()
    {


    int i = 0;
      //defining sub block
      {
            i++; // i is accessible in sub blocks.
            int j = 0;
      }
    //ERROR : j is defined in the sub block, sub block is finished so it's out of scope
      j++; 

    }
```

You solution is to define your variable in a higher scope level. Like at class level
You must define you variable as static obviously.

```
private static  string firstline;
```